# CSS slideshow only shows unordered list instead of wallpapers

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I rewrote code from a tutorial into a CSS slideshow using HTML and CSS only. It used an unordered list with multiple spans in it, created an animation effect with CSS and assigned .jpg files to every list item. There's also a part dealing with browsers that dont support css animations. At first I thought it was just a basic errror while linking the stylesheet but that doesnt seem to be the case or I cant find the exact error. I tried rewriting the whole code while comparing it to what the tutorial said. It still doesn't work, but instead shows the unordered list with no styling. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>My Slideshow doesnt work :/</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "/index.css">
    </head>
    <body id = "page">
            <ul class = "slideshow">
                <li><span>Image 1</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 2</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 3</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 4</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 5</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 6</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 7</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 8</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 9</span></li>
                <li><span>Image 10</span></li>
            </ul>
    </body>
</html>

CSS:
```

```
.slideshow,
.slideshow.slideshow{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.slideshow:after{
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(/img/pattern.png) repeat top left;
}

.slideshow li span{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 72s linear infinite 0s; 
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span{
    background-image: url(./img/img1.jpg);
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img2.jpg);
    animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 24s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img4.jpg);
    animation-delay: 36s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(5) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img5.jpg);
    animation-delay: 48s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(6) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img6.jpg);
    animation-delay: 60s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(7) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img7.jpg);
    animation-delay: 72s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(8) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img8.jpg);
    animation-delay: 84s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(9) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img9.jpg);
    animation-delay: 96s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(10) span{
    background-image: url(/img/img10.jpg);
    animation-delay: 108s;
}



@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

.no-cssanimations .slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`span` elements are inline by default, so you should add `display: block` to the rule for `.slideshow li span`, so that the size and position parameters in it have an effect.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Any other idea?

Comment: well, check your file paths, both for the stylesheet and the background images